# How to make an activity launch itself again (stacking on top of previous activities)?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am implementing a drill-down list with various API calls (depending on how far down the list we currently are).  The first time we open the activity (EventListActivity) it calls APICall1.  When you click on a list item that's populated from the JSON response, it will call APICall2 with a parent ID (from APICall1).  If the data that's returned isn't a child node of the tree, we call APICall2 again with a new parent ID (from the previous APICall2).  If it is a child, we finally call APICall3.

Basically, no matter how I implement it, I will need EventListActivity to call itself and stack on top of previous activities (because users will need to go back to the previous screen).  The issue, though, is when I try to launch EventListActivity from EventListActivity, instead of going through the onCreate and actually relaunching the activity, it is hitting the onResume.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

    if (status == GET_SPORTS) {
        status = GET_CATEGORIES;
        //parent_id = ; //currently hardcoded in

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putInt("status", status);
        params.putInt("parent_id", parent_id);

        //Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, FavoritesActivity.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, EventListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(params);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (status == GET_CATEGORIES) {
        status = GET_EVENTS;
        //parent_id = ; //currently hardcoded in

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putInt("status", status);
        params.putInt("parent_id", parent_id);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, EventListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(params);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (status == GET_EVENTS) {
        //do things!
    }
}
});
```

If I uncomment Intent intent... on line 14 and comment out 15 (launching a new FavoritesActivity instead of an EventListActivity), it works fine and launches the FavoritesActivity just fine.  So I am unsure what is preventing the EventListActivity from relaunching instead of going through its onResume.

I am aware that:

```
    startActivity(intent);
    mActivity.finish();
```

is a quick (and maybe dirty) way to relaunch/recreate an activity, so shouldn't leaving out the mActivity.finish() launch a new EventListActivity on top of itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was in the Android Manifest.  Under this activity, there was the setting:

```
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

that apparently limits the number of times a certain activity can be active to 1.  This is why it was going through the `onResume()` rather than `onCreate()` again.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` should accomplish this, I believe. So change your `Intent` to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, EventListActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtras(params);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This will create a new task on the stack.

Comment: Hmmmm, that looked promising, but it didn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Does it mean same activity is still resuming?

Comment: @codesnooker correct, it is still just going through the onResume and not actually launching a new EventListActivity.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Hmm.. In case if you don't need the very first activity then you can kill it by calling finish() method.

Comment: @codesnooker so what's also odd is when I do `startActivity(intent); mActivity.finish();` it closes the activity but it doesn't launch it again, so it just ends up returning me to the main menu of the app

Comment: What is `mActivity` initialized to? Have you tried using `EventListActivity.this` instead?

Comment: `mActivity = this;` at the beginning of `onCreate()`, I tried `EventListActivity.this` but again, no change.